# How to disable Wi-Fi when PC is shut down

Tags: wifi, reboot

Having upgraded to Ubuntu 23.10, every time I turn off or reboot the unit (with Wi-Fi still connected) it slows down, especially after logging in. 
It keeps looping back to loading screen.

My temporary solution is to shut it down again
by long pressing the power button of my PC and back on. 
It then works as normal.

Can someone please suggest a permanent solution to this?